# How to parse a file with one line in shell

Tags: bash, shell, sh, ksh

This is probably a silly question, but what is the best way to get the string from a text file which has only one line using shell. I know I can use while read, but seems like it might be unecessary.

The file I am reading contains a string directory path, and all I want to do is set that string value to a variable.

```
if [ -e ${DIR}/test.txt ] ; then
    # set the string within the file to a variable
fi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My personal preference is:

```
DIR=$( cat file )
```

but

```
read DIR < file
```

works nicely as well

Comment: In bash and ksh, we can drop `cat`:  `DIR=$( < file )`; this saves a process.

Comment: But in any standard compliant shell, `< file` produces no output.  Yet another example of `bash` being non-compliant!

Answer (score 2):

read is absolutely fine:

```
read var < test.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

How about just using [unix cat](http://www.linfo.org/cat.html)

`var=$(cat ${DIR}/test.txt)`